# Free group with 3 generators and free group with 2 generators

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $F=<a,b>$ the free group with 2 generators and $G=<u,v,w>$ the free group with 3 generators. How can I show that the map $f:G\rightarrow F$ that sends $u\rightarrow ab,v\rightarrow a^2b^2, w\rightarrow a^3b^3$ and extends to $G$ with the obvious way  is a monomorphism?

> I can show that $f$ is a homomorphism but I can't show that it is $1-1$.
>   Is there a way to maybe show it has an inverse?

Comment: Can you figure out the kernel of $f$?

Comment: That you "can show $\;f\;$ is a homomorphism" either makes no sense or else it is trivial, since if you meant *the extended* $\;f\;$ to all $\;G\;$ then it is trivial by the universal property of free groups, whereas if you meant the set map $\;f\;$ as given then it makes no sense...

Comment: Can you show that the subgroup of $\;F\;$ generated by $\;ab,\,a^2b^2,\,a^3b^3\;$ is free? Or what ammounts to the same, that $\;ab,\,a^2b^2,\,a^3b^3\;$ are *free variables* ? Because if you can, and it doesn't look too tough, then you can finish your proof by means of Hopficity of free groups...

Comment: I dont know much about free groups . What do you mean that $ab,a^2b^2,a^3b^3$ are free variables?Also i dont know anything about the hopficity of free groups

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't see why you need Hopficity of free groups for that. Once you know that $x=ab$, $y=a^2b^2$, and $z=a^3b^3$ freely generate the subgroup that they generate, then it follows immediately that $f$ is a monomorphism. And to show that, you need to show that no reduced word in $x,y,z$ can reduce to the identity in $F$, which as you say does not look too hard.

Comment: @MadMax It is difficult to help you without knowing how much you know about free groups. Do you know about Nielsen reduction, which is an algorithm for reducing any set of generators of a subgroup to a free generating set?

Comment: @DerekHolt I mean: how  can I deduce that an epimorphism from a free group to itself (or an isomorphic copy of itself) must be injective without Hopcity? This may be an overkill but I can't see no other, simple way to do that.

Comment: But if $ab$, $a^2b^2$ and $a^3b^3$ freely generate the subgroup $H = \langle ab, a^2b^2, a^3b^3 \rangle$, then $H$ is isomorphic to the free group on generators $u,v,w$, with an isomorphism mapping $u,v,w$ to $ab,a^2b^2,a^3b^3$. That follows directly from the definition of free groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt So you are,in a way, telling me to figure out what the $kerf$ is(it should be  {1}  )?But how can i do that?(i dont know nielsen reduction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the subgroup $H$ generated by $ab$, $a^2b^2$, $a^3b^3$ is also generated by $x = ab$, $y = a^2b^2(ab)^{-1} = a^2ba^{-1}$, and $z = a^3(ab)^{-2}= a^3ba^{-2}$. It is sufficient to prove that $H$ is freely generated by $x,y,z$ because if it is then it is also freely generated by $ab$, $a^2b^2$, and $a^3b^3$.

The point about doing that replacement is that the set $x,y,z$ is Nielsen reduced, but you do not need to know what that means to prove the result.

Note that in any non-cancelling product of two of $x,y,z,x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1}$, the terms $b$ or $b^{-1}$ in the generators do not cancel. For example $yx = a^2b^2$, or $yz^{-1}= a^2bab^{-1}a^{-3}$.

So in any reduced word of length $n$ in the generators $x,y,z$, there will be exactly $n$ letters equal to $b$ or $b^{-1}$. Hence no such word reduces to the identity and it follows that $H$ is freely generated by $x,y,z$.

Comment: Those first transformations are Nielsen tranformations?([i just read about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen_transformation)).I understand now. Thank you very much!