# Matrices that Generate a Free Group

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I know that there are pairs of 2x2 matrices that generate a free group. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1028999969

My question is: Is there a way to construct a set of 3 or more matrices that generate a free group? Even if it involves increasing the dimensions of the matrices, or expanding to the complex plane.

Thanks!

Comment: Free group on two generators has free subgroups of arbitrary rank.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's a much more general theorem: every finitely generated free group is a subgroup of the free group on two generators. So you can find a set of three matrices that generate a free group by taking appropriate products of the two you already have.

Comment: In fact, it has a subgroup isomorphic to the free group on countably many generators!

Comment: I don't quite understand. If A and B generate a free group, A, B and AB can't. (A)(A)(B) = (A)(AB), so the group isn't really free - right?

Comment: @Jesse:  Those aren't "appropriate products".    One example of "approrpriate products" are $ab, a^2b^2,$ and $a^3 b^3$.  See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246267/free-group-with-3-generators-and-free-group-with-2-generators